# I need help regarding perl hash of array

Tags: perl

I have a hash of array and two variables -1 list and 1-scalar value

How do I do this?

I want two things out of this. First is a list for every key.
Second is I need $b to have the value of last array element of every key

```
  %abc=(
        0=>[1,2,3],
        1=>[1,5]
        );
    @a;
    $b;
```

for key 0 i need @a to have [1,2] and for key 1 i need @a to have [1].
for 0 key i need $b to have value 3 and for key 1 i need $b to have value 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you want `@a` to hold all values but last, and `$b` to just hold the last value.  How about:

```perl
use feature 'say';
my %abc = (0 => [1,2,3], 1 => [1,5]);

for my $key (keys %abc) {
    my @a = @{$abc{$key}};
    my $b = pop @a;
    say "@a / $b"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd almost certainly use something like [the other solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56846556/7231). But here's a different solution that a) uses `values()` instead of `keys()` and b) uses `reverse()` to simplify(?!) the assignments. Don't do this :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %abc = (0 => [1,2,3], 1 => [1,5]);

for (values %abc) {
  my ($b, @a) = reverse @$_;
  @a = reverse @a;

  say "@a / $b";
}
```

Comment: there is more than one way to do it!